# No value displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

So I am learning Angular , and I would like to make a web Application which consumes a Restful Web service . So my page looks like this :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Tripeew">
    <head>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Tripeew</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="region">
        <h1>Hello World !!</h1>
             <p>Id : {{All.id}}</p> 
             <p>Nom :{{All.nom}}</p>
             <br/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myapp = angular.module('Tripeew',[]);
            myapp.controller('region',function($scope,$http){
                $http.get('http://localhost:9090/Tripeew_V1.0/webresources/tripeewws.regions/3').succes(function(){
                    $scope.All = response.data ; 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I can't have the result of the ws , which is working via URL , all I get is this :

```
Hello World !!

Id : {{All.id}}

Nom :{{All.nom}}
```

Comment: Rename  `.succes()` to `.success()`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:9090/Tripeew_V1.0/webresources/tripeewws.regions/3').then(function(response) {
    $scope.All = response.data ;
});
```

Error is occured because AngularJS version that author uses is `1.6.9`, but `success()/error()` was deleted in `1.6.0-rc.0` version (**[see Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#http-due-to-1)**).

> **BREAKING CHANGE:**
>
> `$http`'s deprecated custom callback methods - `success()` and
>   `error()` - have been removed. You can use the standard
>   `then()`/`catch()` promise methods instead, but note that the method
>   signatures and return values are different.
>
> `success(fn)` can be replaced with `then(fn)`, and `error(fn)` can be
>   replaced with either `then(null, fn)` or `catch(fn)`.
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> $http(...).
>   success(function onSuccess(data, status, headers, config) {
>     // Handle success
>     ...
>   }).
>   error(function onError(data, status, headers, config) {
>     // Handle error
>     ...
>   });
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> $http(...).
>   then(function onSuccess(response) {
>     // Handle success
>     var data = response.data;
>     var status = response.status;
>     var statusText = response.statusText;
>     var headers = response.headers;
>     var config = response.config;
>     ...
>   }, function onError(response) {
>     // Handle error
>     var data = response.data;
>     var status = response.status;
>     var statusText = response.statusText;
>     var headers = response.headers;
>     var config = response.config;
>     ...
>   });
>
> // or
>
> $http(...).
>   then(function onSuccess(response) {
>     // Handle success
>     var data = response.data;
>     var status = response.status;
>     var statusText = response.statusText;
>     var headers = response.headers;
>     var config = response.config;
>     ...
>   }).
>   catch(function onError(response) {
>     // Handle error
>     var data = response.data;
>     var status = response.status;
>     var statusText = response.statusText;
>     var headers = response.headers;
>     var config = response.config;
>     ...
>   });
> ```
>
> **Note:** There is a subtle difference between the variations showed above. When using `$http(...).success(onSuccess).error(onError)` or
>   `$http(...).then(onSuccess, onError)`, the `onError()` callback will
>   only handle errors/rejections produced by the `$http()` call. If the
>   `onSuccess()` callback produces an error/rejection, it won't be
>   handled by `onError()` and might go unnoticed. In contrast, when using
>   `$http(...).then(onSuccess).catch(onError)`, `onError()` will handle
>   errors/rejections produced by both `$http()` *and* `onSuccess()`.

Comment: @Roman, if you could add what was wrong in his code, that would've been much helpful :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, I have updated my answer with explanation, why author's code was wrong.

Comment: Great. Verbosity always helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `success` syntax is deprecated since Angular 1.4.3. If you're using a newer version of Angular you should use the `then` syntax.

Comment: I did that , but instead of getting {{All.id}} I get nothing

Comment: @MehdiBajjou add `console.log (response.data)` in your `.success()` function and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two problems with your code. First one is obvious as everbody have told you to correct the typo of `sucess` to `success` and second you're not passing response to your handler function that you wrote in success. I mean you should pass the data like `.success((response)=> $scope.All = response.data)`.

Notice, I am passing `response` to success callback.

Moreover, you better use the following syntax to make `http` requests with angularjs

```
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
    url: '/someUrl'
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
     // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```